# url works in the browser but returns nothing in the function

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

I wrote these two functions, hoping to retrieve data from the url,  it works in the browser but do I not get anything in the code

```
function readSensorsData(){
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET","http://192.168.0.1/json", true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = processData;
}
readSensorsData();

function processData(){
  if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
    //------Updat data sử dụng javascript----------
    ketqua = xhttp.responseText; 
    alert(ketqua);

  }
}
```

in this I can only use native javascript.

Comment: Does the page that runs this JavaScript come from the same domain as the AJAX request? On a first glance, this looks like a CORS issue. Also: Did you check the dev tools' network tab to see, if anything is wrong with the request itself?

Comment: If its a cors issue I should see cors error in browser console but i see nothing

Comment: The `xhhtp` variable of `readSensorsData()` is not visible from within `processData()`. You should actually see some error in the console about this. PS: consider using `fetch()` for its simpler API.

Comment: yes fetch worked without any issues

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz regarding the append child i make an answer.But you deleted it .Find it here. http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ed3e59c3400005f0001f525

Comment: I got it working, whoever posted first wrong answer was right, but not exactly . so I returnded div element from `divCreator` and added to `appendChild`